# Sharepoint 2013/0365 Summary Links Snippet in Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, office-365

I am using SPDesigner to create a custom page layout.

I create a page using Design Manager within O356, and then edit the page generated. I have managed to get custom webpart zones in. However I am having issues with Summary Links.

I would like to have 4 zones with Summary Links. The default page comes with one summary links, and it works fine. When I create another one (using the Snippet Generator) and I place the given code in my custom page layout, I get to see it correctly in the page layout preview mode.

After Check-in and publishing a major version of the page layout, when I go to edit the page with my assigned page layout, the summary links zone is (a) empty, (b) not editable.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you found an answer at all?

Comment: Hi Termato, I had found my mistake. SharePoint pages come with a summary links from the page fields, like the page content, and page title to name a couple. I managed to overcome this by using the SummaryLinks snippets generated not from the Page Fields, but form the Dynamic Content. To do this go to design manager, click on page layouts, any page layout of yours. The preview page will open and then you can click on Snippets on the top righ-hand corner. From the ribbon menu chose Dynamic Content > Summary Links. Enjoy :)